# String Parameter in AjaxOption null on Submit but showing in Response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, s#arp-architecture

In this piece of code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyRouteValues", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", '" + Model.StringParameter + "')" }))
```

Why does my Javascript recognize Model.IntegerParameter correctly but Model.StringParameter as `null`?  I am sure it has data on it as I check the response and it shows like this

```
data-ajax-success="myJSFunction(111111, &#39;AAAAAA&#39;)"
```

My View model is really simple and it looks like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int IntegerParameter { get; set; }
    public string StringParameter { get; set; }
}
```

How do I fix this?

**Added Info**

I tried changing the second parameter to int, now its not passing as `null` but `0` and still it shows in the response in FireBug.

I added the Html.Raw, but it still gets a `null` value in Javascript.

Here is a real world screenshot of what I get in the console response:

[image]

**---------------Another Update------------------**

I tried all the suggestions, but it seems to be a ***BUG in <strike>MVC</strike> s#arp***? I tried in different projects and on different PC's it still happens for me.  I noticed this only happens if its coming from a Model it looks like what happens in between the response to Javascript the value of string gets lost regardless whether its the first, second or any position in the parameter but if I use a hard coded value, such as:

```
myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", 'AAAAAAAA')"
```

I get a successful result, also if I use jQuery like such :

```
myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", $('#SearchString').val())"
```

This also works but if I do pass a Model that is a string like such

```
myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", '" + Model.StringParameter + "')"
```

This does not work.

So is you want to see what really happens on real world where I taken account the suggestions of @Darin and @Shark.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you see in the response, it is there but when passed to Javascript, it gets lost.  Here is the real life Javascript as well

```
displayResultsPopUpWindow: function (model) {
    var postData = {
        transactionId: model.transactionId,
        searchString: model.searchString
    };

    $.post("/Invoicing/GetSearchResults", postData, function (data) {
        WindowHelper.displayWindow("Add Airline Transaction", "<div id='matchBookingResults'>" + unescape(data.viewHtml) + "</div>", 640, 500);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in S#arp Architecture so instead of using the model, I just used jQuery to extract the value I needed like such

```
myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", $('#SearchString').val())"
```

Comment: Just tried this with a S#arp Architecture project, and I can't reproduce the problem.

What does the posted data look like when you get a null?

Answer (score 4):

Unable to reproduce the issue. Try like this:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int IntegerParameter { get; set; }
    public string StringParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            IntegerParameter = 1111,
            StringParameter = "AA'AA\"AA"
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return Json(new { foo = "bar" });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJSFunction = function (model) {
        alert('intParam=' + model.intParam + ', strParam=' + model.strParam);
    };
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "MyAction",
    "Home",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "myJSFunction(" + Json.Encode(new { intParam = Model.IntegerParameter, strParam = Model.StringParameter }) + ")"
    }
))
{
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

When the form is submitted using AJAX, the myJSFunction success callback is invoked and passed the correct values.

Comment: Thanks for this reply but still get an error please see my updated info on my question

Comment: @Raymund, I have tried but I am unable to reproduce your issue. It works for me all the time.

Comment: Thats weird, it keeps happening on me, what MVC version are you using? Anyways thanks for the help and +1 for the effort of helping me.  I will still try to find the issue on my end and keep this post updated if I found whats wrong

Comment: @Raymund, I am using ASP.NET MVC 3. If you are able to narrow down your problem to a simple controller and view you could mail me your project and I would be happy to take a look at it in order to tell you what's wrong. Unfortunately at this stage since I cannot reproduce the problem I don't see how I can help further.

Comment: Youre correct this is working must be something to do with s#arp architecture I am using SharpArch.Web.Mvc.ModelBinder, I created a new project without referencing to s#arp architecture it works

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that is an Html-encoded string.  Try doing this:

```
Html.Raw(Model.StringParameter)
```

**Edit**:  Try this:

```
OnSuccess = Html.Raw("myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", '" + Model.StringParameter + "')")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply bu still does not work, I added the screenshot after adding Html.Raw

Comment: @Raymund `&#39` is the HTML char code for an apostrophe.  It's getting encoded somewhere.

Comment: I manually add it in myJSFunction(" + Model.IntegerParameter + ", '" + Model.StringParameter + "')

Comment: @Raymund Right, but that apostrophe that you surround that parameter with doesn't stay raw, it gets encoded to `&#39` when output to the form element.

Comment: If i remove them it gives me an error in jquery....min.js.  Whats shown in console is syntax error  

`InvoiceActions.displayResultsPopUpWindow(447442, )`

Comment: @Raymund See my edit.  Give that a try.  That'll encode your whole JavaScript function call.  That should include the apostrophe to not be encoded.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well shark I still have the issue but will still further look for answer like what I had said to @Darin will update this post if I ever find a fix.  +1 for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Your searchString is null probably because input has name SearchString - letter case has means.